# AWS ECS memory utilization is increasing but not dropping

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, memory-management, amazon-ecs

Spring boot memory usage and AWS ECS memory utilization gap is too big, and memory utilization keeps growing.

Hello,

Sorry for my bad english before starting my question.

I'am  running spring boot(2.5.14) application within a docker(adoptopenjdk/openjdk11) container using AWS ECS.

ECS memory utilization keeps increasing, and the service get killed and restart in the end.
But java memory usages are not that high compare to ECS memory utilzation.

[ecs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydcy6.png)
[java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OO34.png)

Here's my Java JVM Options

```
 "-Xms1g", "-Xmx1g", "-XX:+UseG1GC", "-XX:+UseLargePagesInMetaspace", "-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m" "-XX:+UseStringDeduplication"
```

Here's excerpt from the current Task Definition

```
2048 Task Memory
1 cpu
1500/1024 soft/hard memory limis(mib)
```

I assume xms, xmx options with task definition memory, but not totally sure.
Thank you in advance.